# Increase coautorships

Tags: publications, phd, authorship

I am a PhD student in Economics and I am looking to increase my paper production to be a more competitive candidate on the job market in a couple of years.

So far I have been working on solo projects and one project coauthored with a cohort-mate. However, my understanding is that the best way to increase paper production is to increase coauthorship.

So my question is: how can I find coauthors outside of my department? Is there a physical/digital location that is more prone to coauthor finding? Should I reach out to authors working in my field? Any suggestion is very welcome!

Comment: Do you have an advisor that can connect you to others in your sub-field?

Comment: Do you have something to offer, *e.g.* some specialized method that is useful for others? And do you know who these other people might be?

Comment: @Snijderfrey, that important point is the basis of an answer. Perhaps you should expand it.

Comment: @Buffy I do have an advisor but not sure about the opportunities to connect outside my department. So far I haven't received any suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

This will be harder during the COVID-19 pandemic, but the prior strategy was to submit papers to conferences, go and present them, and then go to see other talks and meet people who share your interests. Now that so many conferences are virtual or hybrid, you’re going to have to get creative, but so is everyone else. Something on SE, FB, TikTok, or the like might be best. Host a weekly article discussion or something similar.  Advertise the heck out of it and let a thousand flowers bloom (hopefully).

Comment: There might be an online-only journal club for grad students in your subject area that you could search for.